# Is it possible to use gdalwarp to create a TIFF file from a vector layer?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

Let's say I have a shapefile that has different polygon geometries as the following:

[image]

I'd like to create a raster with the area inside these polygons filled with a specific color. Something like a hexadecimal color as `#0000FF` (but it could be in a different way too). I know I can use `gdalwarp` to clip shapefies from rasters with the command:

```bsh
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline input.shp -crop_to_cutline input.tif input_clip.tif
```

Knowing that, I know it would be possible to generate a huge raster with the bounding box of my polygons and then use this last command to crop the color inside the polygon's area. So I see two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Generating a bounding box of my polygons that's filled with a specific color. Then I could use my first command to solve the rest of the problem. I don't know if it's possible to use `gdalwarp` for generating a TIFF raster from a vector layer only, most issues that I see here in the forum use it for clipping rasters. Is it possible to generate a raster filled with a specific color from a bounding box input?
2. Creating a colorized TIFF raster from the vector layer directly with a single GDAL command. I've tried searching for this possibility but I'm not sure if it's possible.

My goal here is to create a TIFF raster from a polygon layer that's filled with a single color. Is there any GDAL command I can use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [gdal_rasterize](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html)

> gdal_rasterize Burns vector geometries into a raster.
>
> ```
> Synopsis gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]
>     {[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add]
>     [-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]
>     [-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def] [-to NAME=VALUE]*
>     [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]*
>     [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
>     [-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/UInt64/Int64/Float32/Float64/
>             CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}]
>     [-optim {[AUTO]/VECTOR/RASTER}] [-q]
>     <src_datasource> <dst_filename>
> ```
>
> Description This program burns vector geometries (points, lines, and polygons) into the raster
> band(s) of a raster image. Vectors are read from OGR supported vector
> formats.
>
> ...
>
> The program creates a new target raster image when any of the -of, -a_nodata, -init, -a_srs, -co, -te, -tr, -tap, -ts, or -ot options are used. The resolution or size must be specified using the -tr or -ts option for all new rasters. The target raster will be overwritten if it already exists and any of these creation-related options are used.

If you want a specific colour, you'll need to create a 3 band RGB raster. Otherwise just set the burn value to 1, create a single band and symbolize it the colour of your choice in your GIS.

E.g. `gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ot Byte -tr xpixelsize ypixelsize -l input input.shp output.tif`